# show file address in GUI scilab,why uicontrol returns undefined

Tags: user-interface, scilab

**strong text**I am writing a GUI program by SciLab.
I get a problem.
I want to practice when I choose a file, the address of this file will automatically show on the GUI window.

```
xdel(winsid());
clear;
clc;

//FileInformation=uigetfile(["*.txt"]);
//golbal window parameters
global margin_x margin_y;
global frame_w frame_h plot_w plot_h;
//window parameter initialization
frame_w=300;
frame_h=500;//frame width and height
plot_w=600;
plot_h=frame_h;//plot width and height
margin_x=15;
margin_y=15;//horizontal and vertical margin for elements
defaultfont="arial";
axes_w=3*margin_x+frame_w+plot_w; //axis width
axes_h=2*margin_y+frame_h;
demo=scf(100001);//create window with id=100001 and make it the current one
demo.background=-2;
demo.figure_position=[100 100];
demo.figure_name=gettext("profile prcessing");
demo.axes_size=[axes_w axes_h];
///////////////////////////////////////
//create menu
//remove menus and toolbars
delmenu(demo.figure_id, gettext("&File"));
delmenu(demo.figure_id, gettext("&Tools"));
delmenu(demo.figure_id, gettext("&Edit"));
delmenu(demo.figure_id, gettext("&?"));
toolbar(demo.figure_id,"off");
//new menu/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
*h1=uimenu("parent",demo,"label",gettext...                           /////
("openfile"),"callback","information=uigetfile()");*                  /////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
h2=uimenu("parent",demo,"label",gettext("About"),"callback","About();");

///
function About()
    msg=msprintf(gettext("this program is developed for wear depth...
    measurement. any unclear please contact ben XU"));
    messagebox(msg,gettext("About"),"info","modal");
endfunction
///
//creating a frame
my_frame=uicontrol("parent",demo,"relief","groove","style","frame",...
"units","pixels","position",[margin_x margin_y frame_w frame_h],...
"horizontalalignment","center","background",[1 1 1],"tag","frame control");
//title of frame
my_frame_title=uicontrol("parent",demo,"style","text","string",...
"address of file","units","pixels","position",[30+margin_x ...
 margin_y+frame_h-10 frame_w-60 20],...
 "fontname",defaultfont,"fontsize",16,"horizontalalignment",...
 "center","backgroun",[1 1 1],"tag","title_frame_control");
//
uicontrol("parent",demo,"style","text","string","address",...
"position",[20,240, 180, ...
20],"horizontalalignment","left","fontsize",14,"background",[1 1 1]);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
*uicontrol("parent",demo,"style","edit","string",information,"position",...
[20,240,180,20],"horizontalalignment","left","fontsize",14,"background",...
[0.9 0.9 0.9],"tag","edi");*
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

as I marked by "/" square.
 problems are information,why is not defined? why ? how can I manage it ?

thanks you all in advance.

Comment: This question might be better titled "Why SciLab uicontrol returns undefined"

Comment: You can edit your source code better, put some blank lines, so it is easier to understand.

Comment: help me, plz! anyone help me !

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks are executed in their own environment.

While they inherit the values of all variables defined in the environment, the code of which was actually executed when the callback was initiated, changes to those variables or newly defined variables are local to the callback environment.

You can declare a variable (in your case the variable "information") global in both environments (adding a "global information;" at the beginning of your script and also at the beginning of your callback string) in order to allow the callback code to alter its value also in the calling environment.

Or you can use the "userdata" property of the UI element you use for triggering the call.
Within the callback you can address it through gcbo, which is a handle to the calling element. "set(gcbo,"userdata",uigetfile());" should do the trick.
As h1 is your handle for the UI element where the callback can be triggered in the calling environment, the information about the user selected file would be found in h1.userdata. You would use "information=h1.userdata;" or "information=get(h1,"userdata");".

Answer (score 0):

If you create your menu, menu item and edit widget like this

```
h1 = uimenu("parent",demo,"label",gettext("file"))
uimenu("parent",h1,"label",gettext("openfile"),"callback","h3.string=uigetfile()");
// ...
h3 = uicontrol("parent",demo,"style","edit","string","","position",...
[20,240,180,20],"horizontalalignment","left","fontsize",14,"background",...
[0.9 0.9 0.9],"tag","edi");
```

Then you should be fine.